# Call from an xsl file to another and receiving a response

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

I need to call from an xsl file to another, which receives some parameters and returns a tag which must be added as seen in the output, the parameters I must take from the input message

Input

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://ejemplo.com/servicios">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:Consultar>
         <headerIn>
            <dispositivo>01010101010101010101010101010101</dispositivo>
            <medio>010001</medio>
            <aplicacion>00006</aplicacion>
         </headerIn>
         <bodyIn>
            <field1>1790197948001</field1>
            <field2>0003</field12>
         </bodyIn>
      </ser:Consultar>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and I need this output

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://ejemplo.com/servicios">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:Consultar>
         <headerIn>
            <dispositivo>01010101010101010101010101010101</dispositivo>
            <medio>010001</medio>
            <aplicacion>00006</aplicacion>
            <poli>
                <teller>1</teller>
                <terminal>3</terminal>
            </poli>
         </headerIn>
         <bodyIn>
            <field1>1790197948001</field1>
            <field2>0003</field12>
         </bodyIn>
      </ser:Consultar>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm trying with this xsl code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="dp" exclude-result-prefixes="dp" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/tns" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="headerIn">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>

        <!-- here i need call another xsl file, I want send 2 parameters taked from input, and to  recibe tag poli -->
        <xsl:call-template name="prueba-call-template">
            <xsl:with-param name="param1" select="medio"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="param2" select="aplicacion"/>

        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

prueba-call-template.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions"
    xmlns:ser="http://ejemplo.com/servicios">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="teller"/>
    <xsl:param name="terminal"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">

      <xsl:variable name="result">
        <poli>
            <teller><xsl:value-of select="$teller"/></teller>
            <terminal><xsl:value-of select="$terminal"/></terminal>
        </poli>
      </xsl:variable>

    </xsl:template>
    <poli> <xsl:value-of select="$result"/></poli>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call an XSLT file from another in the way you are thinking. You can, however, include an XSLT file in other, and then call templates that are in that included XSLT.

Firstly, change your prueba-call-template.xsl to this...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions"
    xmlns:ser="http://ejemplo.com/servicios"
        exclude-result-prefixes="dp">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template name="prueba">
        <xsl:param name="teller"/>
        <xsl:param name="terminal"/>
        <poli>
            <teller><xsl:value-of select="$teller"/></teller>
            <terminal><xsl:value-of select="$terminal"/></terminal>
        </poli>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then, you can include this XSLT in your main XSLT with the `xsl:include` statement

```
<xsl:include href="prueba-call-template.xsl" />
```

You would also need to change the `xsl:call-template` to use the correct template and parameter names (In your current XSLT you are calling it with parameters "param1" and "param2" but your second XSLT uses "teller" and "terminal")

```
 <xsl:call-template name="prueba">
     <xsl:with-param name="teller" select="medio"/>
     <xsl:with-param name="terminal" select="aplicacion"/>
 </xsl:call-template>
```

So, your main XSLT would look like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" extension-element-prefixes="dp" exclude-result-prefixes="dp" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/tns" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:include href="prueba-call-template.xsl" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="headerIn">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>

        <xsl:call-template name="prueba">
            <xsl:with-param name="teller" select="medio"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="terminal" select="aplicacion"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that both XSLTs would have to be saved in the same location.